# Talking About Crime: Kriminalität vs. Verbrechen vs. Delikt

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

What are the differences between the words Kriminalität, Verbrechen and Delikt? I understand that all of these words have to deal with crime, but I'd like to know what differences there are between them.

Here are 2 sentences where Google Translate (from English to German) uses Kriminalität and Verbrechen:

> This is a high *crime* area. -> Dies ist ein Gebiet mit hoher *Kriminalität*.
>
> She committed a *crime*. -> Sie hat ein *Verbrechen* begangen.

"Delikten" seems to be used much less by Google Translate. When is the word "Delikten" normally used?

Comment: This must be genitive (or something I'm not sure about) form like _"Sie war schon früher wegen mehrerer Arten von **Delikten** angeklagt"_. The regular plural form of _Delikt_ is _Delikte_. A _Delikt_ refers to a _Verbrechen_ done by a particular person. A _Verbrechen_ is a deed  / fact described by law in an abstract form, or relying on precedence cases.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have noticed that "Delikten" is sometimes used in place of the English word "offense" rather than for "crime". "Offense" and "crime" are _very_ similar words in English. "Offense" is essentially a more formal/professional term for "crime", and you will hear that word a lot in a courthouse. I wonder if "Delikten" is also a more formal word for "Kriminalität" or "Verbrechen" in German?

Comment: _"I wonder if "Delikten" is also a more formal word for "Kriminalität" or "Verbrechen" in German?"_ No, _Delikten_ is a very special plural form used in particular context, e.g. _"Die Anzahl an Tötungs**delikten** ist im vergangenen Jahr merklich zurückgegangen"_.

Comment: Is English your native language? Because even in English these two uses of crime clearly differ: the former is the uncountable crime (a lot of crime, little crime, high crime) that just describes criminal activity in general and would be translated as »Kriminalität«, the latter is the countable crime (a crime, the crime, few crimes, many crimes) which described the criminal act itself and would be translated as e.g. »Delikt«, »Vergehen«, »Verbrechen«.

Comment: @Raketenolli Yes, English is my native language, and I agree that these two uses of "crime" are clearly different and have different meanings. But we still use one word, "crime", in both of the examples, whereas German speakers will use two distinct words between the two examples. I'll admit, my 2nd example isn't necessarily a very realistic example since we wouldn't typically say "She committed a _crime_", we would typically be more specific by naming a specific crime, like "She committed a _burglary_" or "She committed a _felony_ (a felony is any serious crime, analogous to a _verbrechen_)."

Comment: Hast Du Wörterbücher konsultiert und haben die die Frage nicht klären können? Inwiefern nicht?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1)

**Delikt** - any criminal activity

**Verbrechen** - any severe criminal activity

**Kriminalität** is quite abstract and difficult to explain. In general Kriminalität is every crime against another legal entity, but also a collective term for every crime done in a defined area

**Rule of thumb**: Every Verbrechen is a Delikt, but not every Delikt is a Verbrechen. German criminal law states, that every crime with a minimum penality of 1 year (3 in Austria & Switzerland) in prison is a Verbrechen. Everything with a minimum penality of less than 1 year is called a Vergehen.

**For example**: Murder (Tötungsdelikt) is a Verbrechen. Hit and run (Verkehrsdelikt) is a Vergehen. But both are a Delikt.

2)

Delikten is [Delikt](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Delikt)'s Dativ plural form, with no special meaning

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments there is another legal term

**Ordnungswidrigkeit** - minor law infringement, punishable by a fine/warning (not prison)

Comment: Speeding (at least as long as it does not cause an accident) is actually not even a _Vergehen_ (and hence not a _Delikt_ neither), but only a _Ordnungswidrigkeit_.

Comment: For the sake of completion, I feel like the term _Kavaliersdelikt_ should be mentioned when discussing the difference between _Delikt_ and _Verbrechen_.

Comment: *Delikt* may be used not only for a punishable offense but also for an act for which one can claim compensation (damage). I think English legal language has the term *tort* for that. In this sense, *Delikt* is synonymous with *unerlaubte Handlung* in German legal language.

Comment: @Matthias Not correct. It is only a Ordnungswidrigkeit when your a maximum of 20 km/h faster than what's right. Speeding more can give you, depending on how much, points in Flensburg, temporary driving ban, permanent driving ban, or even inprisonment. And yes, it has happened the someone went 180 in a 30 Zone. This is even in Germany punished. (alltough driving punishedments in Germany are a joke)

Comment: http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/justiz/stuttgart-gotthard-raser-sitzt-im-gefaengnis-a-1233527.html

Comment: @GrottenOlm Das Kavaliersdelikt ist eher gesellschaftlicher Natur. Wenn dann das Bagatalldelikt, aber ich denke eines oder beide hier noch zu erwähnen würde zu unübersichtlich werden

Comment: @RHa Yes, _tort_ is the correct word, and as you stated, it is regarding civil law, where people/entities can sue other people/entities for compensation/damages.

Comment: @miep Your example is from Switzerland, where excessive speeding indeed is a crime. But I assumed we were talking about Germany (otherwise the explanation for _Vergehen_ in the answer would not be correct). And here, alas, it is always a _Ordnungswidrigkeit_. You might want to read https://www.bussgeldkatalog.net/geldbusse/ for the difference between a _Geldbuße_ and _Geldstrafe_.

Comment: Your right. I mixed something up there. I knew German traffic laws are bad, but not that they're that useless...